# How to go about getting exact word using angular filter pipe and not words matching the value?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Example if i search [App] i don't want to see [Apple, Appliance, Appliances], instead i want to only see [App] in the search

I was informed to use return filter.map(filterItem => items.filter(itemItem => itemItem === filterItem).join()) but that doesn't seem to work.

```
  @Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, filter: any, isAnd: bool): any {
    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
      if (isAnd) {
        return items.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((memo, keyName) =>
                (memo && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] === "", true));
      } else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            console.log(keyName);
            return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] === "";
          });
        });
      }
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just to clarify, your `items` is an array of string, and the `filter` is just a string. And you want to return only the words from `items` that exactly match the `filter` as an array?

Comment: Yes basically exact words and not words that contains the value in any order.

Example:

BAD - Searched [TOM], Found [TOMMY, TOM]
GOOD - Searched [TOM], Found [TOM]

Comment: But is `items` an array of strings and `filter` just the string to filter with? Or are those two vars objects/array of objects with specific properties? If so could you share what `items` and `filter` look like?

Comment: O ok, so below is what you asked for.

filter = data1,data2,data3
items = [object Object][object Object][object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the `RegExp` string to include word-boundaries (`\b`) before and after the searched word.

Or, you could use anchors (`^`: start of line, `$`: end of line).

Something like:

```
`\\b${filtered_word}\\b`
```

or

```
`^${filtered_word}$`
```